# How to cite a court case found online

Tags: legal-citation

I need to cite one court case for a project I am researching. The *Chicago Manual of Style* says to use Bluebook citation for legal materials. I have a link to the document that I am using, but I am not sure how to cite it.
This is the link to the case: [link here](https://www.govinfo.gov/app/details/USCOURTS-nyed-1_11-cr-00623/summary).

I think my citation should look something like this:

> *USA vs. Hasbajrami* _____ (E.D.N.Y. 2016)

Since I found it online, I'm not sure how to mark the "reporter" field, which I believe should be in the empty space I marked.

How should I cite this? I apologize, I have no experience with law, and despite about an hour of trying to figure out this one citation, I don't think I'm searching for the right things because I can't find anything.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the format for American citations, so I'm not sure if it helps, but [casetext](https://casetext.com/case/united-states-v-hasbajrami) uses this citation: *United States v. Hasbajrami, 11-CR-623 (JG) (E.D.N.Y. Feb. 18, 2016)* If this is correct, then I'll convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is an unreported case, so there is no "reporter" designation. You can cite like this: [*United States v. Hasbajrami*, No. 11-CR-623 (JG), 2016 WL 1029500, at *1 (E.D.N.Y. Mar. 8, 2016)](https://casetext.com/case/united-states-v-hasbajrami).